# AccessViolation during async TCP operations

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp, async-await

I'm continuously getting unhandled `AccessViolationException` during various async TCP operations.
The exception arises only in Disassembly window in built-in function 
`System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)`. Stack trace of the exception contains only this function. Assembly line is: `cmp   dword ptr [ecx], ecx`.
The most annoying thing is that exception arrives irregularly (program can execute 30 minutes or 6 hours or 15 seconds before it).

Here is full exception description:

```cs
System.AccessViolationException unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   in System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
InnerException:
```

The code:
I've got this exception during any tries to access TCP socket async in any way. I don't use external unmanaged code. Here is my last try to connect to group of remote address asynchronously.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PollerCore p = new PollerCore();

        p.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class PollerCore
{
    string[] ip = new string[255];
    public void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            ip[i] = String.Format("192.168.100.{0}", i);
        }
        new Thread(WorkerThread).Start();

    }

    async void WorkerThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In wt... ");
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

            List<Task<string>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            foreach (string addr in ip)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(addr)) continue;
                tasks.Add(ConnectToDevice(addr));
            }
            string[] res = await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

            foreach (string s in res)
            {
                if (s != null) Console.WriteLine("Connecting to {0}... DONE", s);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    async Task<string> ConnectToDevice(string ip)
    {
        using (TcpClient c = new TcpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                await c.ConnectAsync(ip, 5100);
                return ip;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Update:
The same exception raised in code reworked according **Noseratio** suggestions. Thread.Start was replaced with Task.Run. In

```cs
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

I was receiving only SocketExceptions with code 10060 (Timeout)...

Comment: My vote would be between hardware failure, malware or bad drivers.  Check event log, updated drivers, and try it on a different computer.  In a distant fourth place would be some sort of actual framework issue, but that seems exceedingly unlikely given the mundane sample you provided.

Comment: Perhaps you right, but unfortunately I haven't noticed any things in event logs or drivers. I think I'll try to shutdown antivirus soft and then on another machine... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be here:

```
new Thread(WorkerThread).Start();

// ...

async void WorkerThread() 
{
    // ...
}
```

Try changing it to this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => WorkerThreadAsync());
task.Wait(); // for debugging

// ...

async Task WorkerThreadAsync() 
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, don't use a separate thread at all:

```
var task = WorkerThreadAsync();
task.Wait(); // for debugging
```

You use async APIs inside `WorkerThread` anyway, a switch to a different pool thread will most likely occur after the first `await`.

A few more things:

- Don't do this: `catch { return null }`. Dump the actual exception information.
- You are disposing of the `TcpClient` as soon as the `ConnectAsync` task has completed, i.e. once the client has connected to the server: `using (TcpClient c = new TcpClient()) { ... }`. Are you really no longer using the `TcpClient` object after that?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll test your solution right now, but as I said before, I'm getting this exception in every code that access sockets in async manner... e.g. I got it when trying MSDN socket sample (Socket.BeginConnect, Socket.EndConnect) with only slight modifications.

Comment: @kurchavy, I don't see anything related to `Socket.BeginConnect`, `Socket.EndConnect`. You're using `ConnectAsync` which is the right thing, but note the update I just posted about this.

Comment: In this case I really don't need any information about the unconnected devices :) In more complicated cases I centainly do smth adequate with exceptions.

Comment: @kurchavy, it doesn't matter. You may just have swallowed an exception  which later may result in the `AccessViolationException`. Avoid a coding style like this.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you on "return null". The matter is that this code is very simplyfied code snippet which was made in debugging purposes. Thats why I dispose TcpClient as soon as it connects to the device.